# Is it ok to have multiple webviews in a single screen?

Tags: android, html, performance, android-activity, webview

Is it a good practice to use many webviews in a single view?

I want to place 5 views that would be easier to implement by using 5 webviews instead of making a single webview JavaScript that holds these 5 views.

However, I believe that the webview is a complex component so this may affect low-end devices performance.

Is this true or there is nothing bad with implementing several webviews into a single view? mostly asking because implementing complex JavaScript in low-end devices may not work as expected.

Comment: Depends on what they're displaying, most likely.  Lots of text-  no problem.  Lots of javascript-  may be an issue.  It would be an unusual design to be sure.

Comment: I think that 5 * bad performance is worst than 1 * bad performance. As far as I could experience, even a single text only Webview with little JavaScript (say to open/close divs on click) performs not so good (not to say bad).

Comment: There's quite a bit of overhead for every WebView. You shouldn't use more than one at a time, but I recommend even fewer than that :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Html Webviews are very lightweight. The normal User Interface in Android itself is XML. So it is not a bad thing to use multiple Webviews. The normal HTML will not produce much overhead compared to XML, but if you use a lot of JavaScript at runtime, that can make an overhead for sure.

Comment: I have a feeling the author of this response is not qualified to answer the question. "The normal HTML will not produce much overhead compared to XML" - the fact that XML is (sometimes) used to define the structure of native screens is not at all relevant.